# Cassandra/Pycassa: get_slice()/get_indexed_slice() fails with TApplicationException: Unknown Result

Tags: python, exception, cassandra, thrift, pycassa

When gettings rows from Cassandra via Pycassa sometimes a `TApplicationException: get_slice failed: unknown result]`.

I'm not able to reproduce this Exception nor can I find any documentation on this issue. Right now I'm running Cassandra as a single node (for development) and the Exception is always raised in a context where a lot of concurrent requests are happening. 
I'd like to know if the reason for this is something like a performance issue or if it is related to something else (therefore I'd like to know if it may disappear when running more than one node in production?).

Cassandra Version is 1.0.7 and the output from the log is the following:

```
[DEBUG 17:45:58,253 Thrift transport error occurred during processing of message.
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor.process(Cassandra.java:2877)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
DEBUG 17:45:58,315 logged out: #<User allow_all groups=[]>]
```

Comment: what are you seeing in the cassandra logs and what version of cassandra?

Comment: @sdolgy: I have updated the question above!

Comment: What is your pycassa console log, and your keyspace (run cassandra-cli and type describe ksName; )

Comment: I would try upgrading to Cassandra 1.0.10 since you're not in production.  No point in trying to debug something that might already be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using multiprocessing, [pycassa.pool is not multiprocessing-safe](http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/using_with/multiprocessing.html).

I was receiving "TApplicationException: get_slice failed: unknown result" under similar circumstances.  I created multiple pycassa.pools, one pool per process, and the problem appears solved.

The documentation has a special page to advise us about multiprocessing and pools, but it does not list what error you will get if you multiprocess with one pool.  I think this is it!